# Accessing the pardiso solver from MKL 2020 in python

Tags: python, pardiso

How can I access the pardiso solver from Intel's MKL in python? On anaconda3, I can `import mkl`. Here is my mkl's version.

```
In [4]: mkl.get_version()
Out[4]:
{'MajorVersion': 2020,
 'MinorVersion': 0,
 'UpdateVersion': 2,
 'ProductStatus': b'Product',
 'Build': b'20200624',
 'Processor': b'Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions 2 (Intel(R) AVX2) enabled processors',
 'Platform': b'Intel(R) 64 architecture'}
```

I do not see pardiso in mkl's accessible modules, so have no idea how the pardiso solver can be made available from python.

```
In [5]: dir(mkl)
Out[5]:
['__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 '__version__',
 '_mklinit',
 '_py_mkl_service',
 'cbwr_get',
 'cbwr_get_auto_branch',
 'cbwr_set',
 'disable_fast_mm',
 'domain_get_max_threads',
 'domain_set_num_threads',
 'dsecnd',
 'enable_instructions',
 'free_buffers',
 'get_clocks_frequency',
 'get_cpu_clocks',
 'get_cpu_frequency',
 'get_dynamic',
 'get_env_mode',
 'get_max_cpu_frequency',
 'get_max_threads',
 'get_version',
 'get_version_string',
 'mem_stat',
 'peak_mem_usage',
 'second',
 'set_dynamic',
 'set_env_mode',
 'set_memory_limit',
 'set_mpi',
 'set_num_threads',
 'set_num_threads_local',
 'six',
 'thread_free_buffers',
 'verbose',
 'vml_clear_err_status',
 'vml_get_err_status',
 'vml_get_mode',
 'vml_set_err_status',
 'vml_set_mode',
 'warnings']
```

Comment: There is an interface called pypardiso to the old MKL Pardiso. Maybe that helps? https://github.com/haasad/PyPardisoProject